# How to store image and retrieve from the folder using codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to the CodeIgniter programming.I want to store and retrieve image from the folder.But  when i run the code i found the error like:

First Error:

```
Upload failed!

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: in

Filename: controllers/main.php

Line Number: 104
```

Second Error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: application/models/main_model.php

Line Number: 80
```

I am using this code:

In Control:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Main extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('main_model');
     $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}
  public function product()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('productname','Product Code','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('productcode','Product Code','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('productprice','Product Price','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity','Quantity','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('uploadimage','Upload Image','trim|required');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
    {
        $this->index();
    }else
        {
            if ($this->input->post('upload'))
            {
                $in=array();

$in['productname']    = $this->input->post('productnamename');
$in['productcode'] = $this->input->post('productcode');
$in['productprice']=$this->input->post('productprice');
$in['quantity']=$this->input->post('quantity');
$in['uploadimage']=$_FILES['image']['name'];
            }
            if($this->main_model->do_upload()) {

echo $this->upload->display_errors();

}else
    {
        $this->main_model->save_gallery($in);
        header('location:product');
    }
            $data['images']=$this->main_model->get_images();
              $this->load->view('query_view',$data);
        }
}
```

In Model:

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Main_model extends CI_Model {
 public function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
 }
    public function do_upload()
{
         $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|bmp', 
        'upload_path'=>'./uploads/', //make sure you have this folder
        'max_size'=>2000);
         $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
        echo "Upload success!";
    } else {
        echo "Upload failed!";
    }
 $image_data = $this->upload->data();
}  
 function get_images()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('product');
    return $query;
}

function save_gallery($in)
{
$save=$this->db->get("product");
if($save->num_rows())
{
$save=$this->db->insert('product',$in);
return $save;
}
}
```

In View:

```
 <?php foreach ($images as $image):?>
<h1><?php echo $image['a_name'];?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $image['a_details'];?></h1>
<?php echo '<img src ="'. base_url().'images1/'.$image['a_photo'].'" >";
 endforeach; ?>
```

FronPage View:

```
<?php echo form_open("main/product"); ?>
    <p>
        <label for="product_name">Product Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="productname" name="productname"       value="<?php echo set_value('product_name'); ?>" />
    </p>        


    <p>
        <label for="ProductCode">Product Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="productcode" name="productcode" value="<?php echo set_value('productcode'); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="productprice">Product Price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="productprice" name="productprice" value="<?php echo set_value('productprice'); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <select name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<?php echo set_value('quantity'); ?>" /><option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>

    </p>  
    <p>
        <label for="Uploadimage">Upload Image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="uploadimage" id="uploadimage" value="<?php echo set_value('uploadimage'); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="greenButton" value="submit" />
    </p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, read the documentation at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html.  Follow it verbatim, nothing fancy, no database, no extra conditionals.  Get that working and add new functionality incrementally in very small portions.  As you encounter problems look around for the answer.

Now for the problem..

You are not getting a value for `$this->input->post('upload')` which is only one of many issues.

Your form open should be

`<?php echo form_open_multipart("main/product"); ?>`

The error below generally indicates that you are passing an empty variable to the `insert` function

```
A Database Error Occurred

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: application/models/main_model.php

Line Number: 80
```

Why are you passing an empty variable?  You are calling the `do_upload` method which always returns void, so, the `TRUE` condition is never met in the code below.

```
if($this->main_model->do_upload()) {
  echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
else
{
  $this->main_model->save_gallery($in);
  header('location:product');
}
```

Verify you are passing the input named `upload` in the form, and the condition for upload should be more like this

```
    if(isset($_FILES['upload']['name']))
    {
        $in=array();

        $in['productname']    = $this->input->post('productnamename');
        $in['productcode'] = $this->input->post('productcode');
        $in['productprice']=$this->input->post('productprice');
        $in['quantity']=$this->input->post('quantity');
        $in['uploadimage']=$_FILES['image']['name'];

        // moved to inside the post('upload') conditional
        if($this->main_model->do_upload()) {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->main_model->save_gallery($in);
            header('location:product');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Your form `enctype` must be `multipart`

2) your are checking `post` instead of `$_FILES`

it should be `if ($this->input->post('upload'))` to  `if ($_FILES['upload']['name'])` for this reason it is not coming in your if block therefore `$in` is undefined when you call

```
$this->main_model->save_gallery($in);
```

when `$in` is undefined therefore you see erro `You must use the "set" method to update an entry.`
in the  model

Hope it makes sense

Comment: How to use set method dianuj?can u please tell me.i am new to the codeigniter programming.

Comment: You dont have to use `set` CI will use automatically you just have to pass `$in` with values , currently your sending `$in` empty or as undefined therefore error occurs once it has values it will works perfect